# Levi-Civita property in Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, relativity, tensor-calculus

There's this property regarding Levi-Civita symbols:

$$\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}=\left|\begin{matrix}\delta_{\alpha\mu}&\delta_{\alpha\nu}&\delta_{\alpha\rho}\\\delta_{\beta\mu}&\delta_{\beta\nu}&\delta_{\beta\rho}\\\delta_{\gamma\mu}&\delta_{\gamma\nu}&\delta_{\gamma\rho}\end{matrix}\right|$$

The question is: in special relativity, Kronecker deltas should be replaced by the metric tensor?

Comment: You mean in 2+1D?

Comment: In general, tensor identities are true regardless of signature. However, in 3+1-dimensional special relativity, the Levi-Civita symbol would have 4 indices, not 3.

Comment: Are you asking about Levi-Civita **symbols** or **tensors**? The former is just a bunch of -1's, 0's, and +1's and independent of the metric, while the latter is a tensor density and subject to general coordinate transformations and depends on the choice of metric. I think you can guess the answer according to which one you are asking.

Comment: I had problems writing 4x4 matrices I'm sorry. It should be a 4-index Levi-Civita symbol @BenCrowell

Comment: It appears in a trace of a Feynman diagram so... @OktayDoğangün

Comment: It could be the both cases, since some of old textbooks and articles denote the Minkowski metric by $\delta_{\mu\nu}$. However your question is valid whatever it appears for.  If $\epsilon$'s are tensor densities the right-hand side of the identity should be in terms of metric tensors and the determinant of the metric, since the identity should transform as tensor density. On the other hand, if they are symbols then the rhs would be just a collection of numbers like the left-hand side, and therefore Kronecker deltas. Maybe I better write these as a proper answer.